# Сделать плавное движение объекта после нажатия на экран(TouchPhase.Began)

Tags: unity3d

Здравствуйте дорогие друзья. Вопрос следующий: Дергается объект сильно при движении. Если убрать `if (Input.touchCount > 0 && Input.GetTouch(0).phase == TouchPhase.Began)` из кода то объект движется плавно как надо. Как реализовать движение плавным после касания по экрану?

```
 public Transform target;

private Vector3 _startPos;
private Vector3 _endPos;
void Start()
{

    _startPos = transform.position;
    _endPos = target.position;
}

void Update()
{
    if (Input.touchCount > 0 && Input.GetTouch(0).phase == TouchPhase.Began)
        transform.position = Vector3.Lerp(_startPos, _endPos, Time.time);
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Для сглаживания движения между кадрами обычно используют `Time.deltaTime` - это время, за которое кадр был обработан. Ну и, судя по всему, вы не совсем верно поняли, как работает интерполяция.

Метод `Vector3.Lerp` возвращает вам позицию от начальной до конечной точки согласно t. Однако, t - должен находиться между 0 и 1, т.е. если вы передаёте `Vector3.Lerp(_startPos, _endPos, 0.5f);` то получите позицию ровно посередине.

Таким образом t - вам нужно рассчитывать и чаще всего оно является соотношением того времени, которое прошло от начала движения к тому времени, за которое ваш "персонаж" должен пройти путь.

Я бы предложил вам использовать [Vector3.MoveTowards](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Vector3.MoveTowards.html). Он принимает от вас две позиции и максимальное смещение, которое вы разрешаете ему сделать. В данном случае вам не придётся рассчитывать время и вы сможете управлять скорость движения персонажа. Например, вот так:

```
[SerializeField]
float _velocity = 10;

void Update()
{
    if (Input.touchCount > 0 && Input.GetTouch(0).phase == TouchPhase.Began)
        transform.position = Vector3.MoveTowards(transform.position, _endPos, Time.deltaTime * _velocity);
}
```

В данной реализации ваш персонаж будет двигаться от своего текущего положения в сторону целевой точки, пока он не достигнет этой точки, либо пока вы не уберёте палец от экрана.

Скоростью движения можно управлять изменяя переменную `_velocity`.

Comment: Ну так то в данном случае можно еще и `LerpUnclamped` использовать :)

Comment: @RiotBr3aker, не совсем понял, где и зачем? о.о

Comment: вместо обычной интерполяции, будет работать с Time.time.

Comment: @RiotBr3aker, так а разве это не приведёт к тому, что он пойдёт в сторону точки и просто пройдёт мимо в какой-то момент?

Comment: Пардон, не вдумался в вопрос. Подумал, что человек использует 2 позиции, как направляющие. Тогда да, `Time.time` тут в принципе не подойдет.

Answer (score 0):

Думаю что проблема в Time.time   оно возвращает время от начала кадра. По сути при каждом таче оно будет разным. Думаю стоит копать в эту сторону. Ведь если нету задержки в виде тача то всё идёт нормально.  Мне так кажется. Попробуйте указать какое то стабильное время. Типа секунды. Если будет норм то точно проблема со временем. И ещё как вариант что ему просто не хватает времени на действие. Из-за условия. Ведь как только тач перейдет в другую фазу то условие не будет срабатывать

Answer (score 0):

сделайте bool, при вашем условии (Input.touchCount > 0 && Input.GetTouch(0).phase == TouchPhase.Began) сделайте ее True. И Так же в Update второе условие, если этот bool true, то transform.position = Vector3.Lerp(_startPos, _endPos, Time.time). В вашем случае он двигается, когда вы двигаете пальцами, а не один раз нажали и он начал движение самостоятельно.